# return a list by reading a text file

Tags: python

I am reading a text file separated by space,the file looks like:

first line:hello    2928977    [1.2,9.7]

second line: apple    6723547    [8.2,3.1]

....

I want to return a list like[(hello,1.2,9.7),(apple,8.2,3.1),...] 
how do i do this?
I know the first step is to set an empty list and then do

```
    output =[]
    inputfile = open('text.txt','r')
    for eachline in inputfile:
            l=line.strip()
            s=l.split(',')
            output.append((s[0],float(s[2][0]),float(s[2][1]))
    return output
```

but this doesn't work... it says invalid syntax....can someone help me?
also I tried with another file with this method, but it says strings cannot be converted into float... i can't get this working, I would really appreaciate your help!Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would usually use regex for this sort of pattern matching to make sure that the elements within `[..]` are numbers. 
But to continue with what you're doing:

```
#s='hello 2928977 [1.2,9.7]\napple 6723547 [8.2,3.1]\n'
#sp=s.splitlines()
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    sp=f.readlines()

output=[]
for p in sp:
    words = p.split(" ")
    x,y=[float(x) for  x in words[2].strip("[|]").split(",")]
    output.append((words[0], x,y ) )
print(output)
```

Comment: `readlines()` stores the whole file into memory via a list, and is not practical here.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi from where did you understand that it was impractical? `readlines()` exists for a reason -- in some cases it's perfectly acceptable to load it into memory, such as when the file is small.

Comment: You're looping through a file to create a data structure to loop through again. The only time `readlines()` is practical is when you need to access the same file contents more than once and you have the memory to do it. It is both bad practice, and impractical here.

Answer (score 0):

Narrowly addressing the invalid syntax, count your parentheses, both open:

```
output.append((s[0],float(s[2][0]),float(s[2][1]))
             ^^          ^              ^
```

and close:

```
output.append((s[0],float(s[2][0]),float(s[2][1]))
                                 ^              ^^
```

See the problem? When you see a `SyntaxError` on a line where it makes no sense, look for mismatched parens, brackets, etc. that began on a previous line; the error usually occurs because the next line after the mismatch is being interpreted as part of the previous line, and of course it's not syntactically valid.

Comment: I add the bracket, but it now says return out of function

Comment: @joe: Do you have a function? I assumed you only posted a snippet, but if that's all the code, of course it's wrong. `return` only makes sense inside a function; if this is at the top level, you can `print` to screen or write to files or whatever, but there is nowhere to return *to*.

Comment: yes... i forgot to put my function.. but now it gives an error: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

1. `split` by `' '` instead of `','`
2. `ast.literal_eval` the string `'[1.2,9.7]'` to get a list `[1.2,9.7]`

---

```
from ast import literal_eval

output = []
with open('text.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    for eachline in inputfile:
        l = eachline.strip()
        s = l.split(' ')
        ls = literal_eval(s[2])
        output.append((s[0], ls[0], ls[1]))
print(output)
# [('hello', 1.2, 9.7), ('apple', 8.2, 3.1)]
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `eval` as a legitimate way to accomplish this. Both `ast.literal_eval` and `json.loads` could be used to do this efficiently and safely, `eval` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Comment: It is a safe version of eval to parse a string and return a value. It avoids executing dangerous code. Both `eval("1")` and `ast.literal_eval("1")` returns 1. `eval("print(1)")` executes the code while `ast.literal_eval("print(1)")` will raise an exception.

Comment: Most importantly, `ast.literal_eval('__import__("shutil").rmtree("/")')` doesn't start deleting all the files on your disk (until it hits a permission error anyway). `eval` is much more "helpful" there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should tell us `invalid syntax` happend in which line. It may cause by <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> or something else.

Second, you can `print` `s[2][0]` and `s[2][1]`.
I guess it may like this:

`[8.2` and `3.1]`, so it can not be converted into float.

You can modify it like this:

`output.append((s[0],float(s[2][0][1:]),float(s[2][1][:-1]))`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are trying to get tuple inside a list.

```
output_list = []

with open('answer.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().rstrip('\n')
    for line in data.split('\n'):
    line_updated = line.strip("[").strip(']').split(' ')
    required_elements = line_updated[0], line_updated[2]

    output_list.append(required_elements)

print('\n',output_list)

[('hello', '1.2,9.7'), ('apple', '8.2,3.1')]
```

Comment: I knew the first code was wrong so had to do a run to make changes. I did what I could when there was no answer to let OP know that answer was on the way. I don't think you need to deride me or else over here. Everyone is learning. Thanks.